# Unityで発音遅延を解決方法

Tags: unity3d

初めて質問させていただきます。Unity初心者です。
円形ボタンを押すと色が切り替わって音が出るサンプルを作成しましたが、SEを再生する時に遅延が出てきました。
サウンドファイルのImport Settings > Load type はLoad into memoryにし、
Project Settings > Audio > DSPBuffer Size はBest latencyにしました
以下がその処理です。

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchTest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    AudioSource SoundMaterial;

    void Start()
    { 
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.gray;
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

発音遅延を減らす方法についてご教授をお願いできませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

■環境
Surface Pro 4
Unity 5.3.0f4 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start(){
    soundMaterial= GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
```

OnMouseDownで

```
soundMaterial.Play();
```

毎回コンポーネントを直に読みに行くのはとても重い処理です
初回に変数に参照を取っておきましょう。

Comment: GetComponent<AudioSource>();

Answer (score 0):

Unityはしばらく触れていないので、違っているかもしれませんが。

AudioSourceに割り当てられているAudioClipの「Preload Audio Data」はオンになっていますか?
デフォルトでオンになっているらしいので、大丈夫だと思いますが。

- 「[Unity実習２７、音を鳴らしてみよう](http://toto0129.blog100.fc2.com/blog-entry-1183.html)」の3番目の画像あたりを参照

Comment: はい、「Preload Audio Data」はオンになっています。